# generating a table in R, with defined parameters

Tags: r, arrays, multiple-columns

I would like to generate a table with 2 columns, with pre-defined parameters for each column, like the picture below:

[image]

What I have in R code so far for the first column is:

```
current_point<-50
lower_bound<-40
upper_bound<-60
size<-2
seq(start,end,by=size)
```

I am able to generate an array from the lines, however, I am stuck when it comes to the second column after I define the needed parameters:

```
value_A<-3
fixed_point<-54
```

Can you please help? Million thanks.

Comment: I'm inferring you meant `seq(lower_bound,upper_bound,by=size)` instead of using `start`/`end` (not defined here). Are you aware of `ifelse`? It's a close match to Excel's `=IF(., ., .)` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good fit for `ifelse`.

```r
col1 = seq(lower_bound,upper_bound,by=size)
ifelse(col1 < fixed_point, col1 - fixed_point + value_A, value_A)
#  [1] -11  -9  -7  -5  -3  -1   1   3   3   3   3
```

Incidentally, I think you can reduce this with `pmin`:

```r
pmin(col1 - fixed_point + value_A, value_A)
#  [1] -11  -9  -7  -5  -3  -1   1   3   3   3   3
```

This is doing a vectorized (element-by-element) minimum.

Even more code reduction, in the form of algebraic factoring:

```r
pmin(col1 - fixed_point, 0) + value_A
#  [1] -11  -9  -7  -5  -3  -1   1   3   3   3   3
```

Answer (score 1):

For the given requirements we could do it this way:

```
#First column: 

lower_bound <- 40
upper_bound <- 60
size <- 2

first_column <- seq(lower_bound, upper_bound, by = size)

#Second column:
value_A <- 3
fixed_point <- 54

second_column <- ifelse(first_column <= fixed_point, value_A - (fixed_point - first_column), value_A)

#df
data.frame(Column1 = first_column, Column2 = second_column)
```

output:

```
   Column1 Column2
1       40     -11
2       42      -9
3       44      -7
4       46      -5
5       48      -3
6       50      -1
7       52       1
8       54       3
9       56       3
10      58       3
11      60       3
```